# Laravel not able to pass userId to the model query

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables one a master table for **providers**  and another a mapping table for **provider-user** which has mapping ID with additional fields which are user specific.

I get values in return if I have the below code.

```
return $mobileProviders=Provider::whereHas('providerUser', function ($query) {
           $query->where('user_id',1);
      })->where('provider_type',1)->get();
```

Now I pass Auth $userId it does not returns any value When I return **$userId** I get **1** which is same as the above but I could not get the result.

```
$userId=Auth::user()->id;
return $mobileProviders=Provider::whereHas('providerUser', function ($query) {
           $query->where('user_id',$userId);
      })->where('provider_type',1)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `use ($userId)` after `function ($query)`. like below:

```
$userId=Auth::user()->id;

return $mobileProviders = Provider::whereHas('providerUser', function ($query) use ($userId) {
           $query->where('user_id',$userId);
      })->where('provider_type',1)->get();
```

This will pass the variable to closure.